# How can I get failed/dropped calls information programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

How can I get failed/dropped calls information? Do we have any private api?

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 10.0+, consider using CallKit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit.

---

On iOS 4.0–10.0, consider checking iOS Call Center API: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcallcenter

Example:

```
self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];

self.callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* call) {


    if ([call.callState isEqualToString:CTCallStateIncoming]) {


    } else if ([call.callState isEqualToString:CTCallStateDialing]) {


    } else if ([call.callState isEqualToString:CTCallStateConnected]) {


    } else if ([call.callState isEqualToString:CTCallStateDisconnected]) {


    }
```

Comment: I want to capture if a call drops or fails. How can I do that?

Comment: Just check if there was no "CTCallStateConnected" state before "CTCallStateDisconnected". In the proper outgoing GSM call you should get: dialing, connected and then disconnected.

Comment: okay. How will I identify whether it is failed call or dropped call if such case occurs?

Comment: Don't think you can with this API, but try to simulate both scenarios and check callID and callState for each, maybe there is a difference.